# How to change background color on each mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css

I am a beginner in HTML and CSS, once I faced this logo on the header that changes color after every mouseover: www.artlebedev.ru . How to do this? I opened html-page and looked through css on this page but have not found how it was done.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please add your HTML code

Comment: that's not possible only with CSS . it uses javascript

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is not a question. Find some code, try it, come back with errors.

Comment: _"I am a beginner"_ read some tutorials. Don't come to SO first...

Answer (score 1):

I had some free time so i decided to help you on this matter. The effect you want uses javascript ( it cannot be done with just CSS ) . In the example below all colors are randomly selected using `random()`

the values of RGB ( red green blue ) are randomly selected each time you hover over the div. Their combination results in a random color.

In the future i suggest you search and research before asking on SO . Also, these are complicated issues that are not suitable for a `css/html beginner` . You should start with some tutorials, master html and css , then turn to javascript and it's libraries, like JQuery

```js
$("div").mouseover(function() {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var bckColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
  $(this).css({
    "background-color": bckColor
  })
})
```

```css
div {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mihai!

Comment: @NikitaLavrukhin glad i could help. if my solution answeres your question, please rate it as acceoted. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Use below code,

$('#logo').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).attr('style','background-color:rgb('+rand(0,255)+','+rand(0,255)+','+rand(0,255)+')');
});

Where logo is id of element you want to change color